# One question about remainder of division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Definition of the Division Algorithm: if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, then there exist unique $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$a=qb+r, 0 \leq r < |b|$$.

My questions are: (1) is this statement provable? i.e can we prove that such q,r exist?
(2) i understand that $r$ can be zero (when $b$ divides $a$) but why is that $r$ must be less than the absolute value of $b$?

Comment: "*Why is [it] that $r$ must be less than the absolute value of $b$?*"  Because it is *useful* for us to force this condition.  It is an artificial restriction that we ourselves imposed on $r$.  Further, by imposing this condition, we make it so that $q$ and $r$ are in fact unique.  Uniqueness would have been lost if we allowed $r$ to be anything.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it can be proved.
2. Because if $a=bq+r$ and $r\geqslant|b|$, you can write $a=b(q+1)+r-b$ if $b>0$ and $a=b(q-1)+r+b$ otherwise. In each case, the new remainder ($r\pm b$) is closer to $0$. And if it is not close enough, you can do the same thing all over again.